# Python bin sets of pairs of interleaving arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a set of pairs of numpy arrays. Each array in a pair is the same length, but arrays in different pairs have different lengths. An example of a pair of arrays from this set is:

```
Time: [5,8,12,17,100,121,136,156,200]
Score: [3,4,5,-10,-90,-80,-70,-40,10]
```

Another pair is:

```
Time: [6,7,9,15,199]
Score: [5,6,7,-11,-130]
```

I need to take an average (or perform binning) of all of these pairs based on the time. i.e. the time should be divided into intervals of 10 and the corresponding score(s) for each interval need to be averaged.

Thus, for the above 2 pairs, I want the following result:

```
Time: [1-10,11-20,21-30,31-40,41-50,...,191-200]
Score: [(3+4+5+6+7)/5, (5-10-11)/2, ...]
```

How can I do this? Is there a simpler way to do this than bin everything individually and then take the average? How do you bin an array based on the bins of another array? i.e. for an individual pair of arrays, how can I bin the time array into intervals of 10 and then use this result to bin the corresponding score array in a consistent manner?

Comment: Just to clarify, the average for range (10-20) shouldn't be `(5-10-11)/3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scipy.stats.binned_statistic`. This is a generalization of a histogram function. A histogram divides the space into bins, and returns the **count** of the number of points in each bin. This function allows the computation of the **sum, mean, median, or other statistic** of the values (or set of values) within each bin.

```py
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

T1 = [5,8,12,17,100,121,136,156,200]
S1 = [3,4,5,-10,-90,-80,-70,-40,10]

T2 = [6,7,9,15,199]
S2 = [5,6,7,-11,-130]

# Merging all Times and Scores in order
Time = T1 + T2
Score = S1 + S2

output = stats.binned_statistic(Time, Score, statistic='mean',range=(0,200), bins=20)

averages = output[0]

# For empty bins, it generates NaN, we can replace them with 0
print( np.nan_to_num(averages, 0) )

# Output of this code: 
# [  5.          -5.33333333   0.           0.           0.
#    0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
#  -90.           0.         -80.         -70.           0.
#  -40.           0.           0.           0.         -60.        ]
```

For more information follow [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html).